# How to best perform graceful degradation on Android Exceptions

Tags: android, exception

I have always wondered if there is an elegant way to handle exceptions atleast notify users and ensure the application doesnot close

This is how i do Exception Handling currently Can you suggest of there is a better pattern available.

```
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);;
        User user = null;
        try {
            user = mapper.readValue(cmsg.message(), User.class);
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            Log.e("User Parsing", "JsonParseException in deserializing user",
                    e.getCause());
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            Log.e("User Parsing", "JsonMappingException in deserializing user",
                    e.getCause());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("User Parsing", "IOException in deserializing user",
                    e.getCause());
        }
        finally{
            Toast.makeText(activity, globalError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
            activity.recreate();
        }
```

Comment: If this code works and you only want to know if it can be made better, try taking it to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I need a coding pattern that can be applied globally to achieve this as mentioned in the question. It will be awesome to have code reuse to dry up Activity Methods. I think it belongs here.

Comment: I don't believe that there is a global pattern. Each framework method throws different exceptions and those exceptions might have different meanings depending on the app context. For a crude example, imagine I write an app to test if a web server is down. I might try to open a socket to port 80.  If is throws an exception, then I have "succeeded".  I catch the exception and carry on, If my app is to download some data from that server, then the exception is a failure case. Is it permanent?  Is it retriable? Should I tell the user? If I do, is there anything they can do about it?  etc.

Comment: I wonder how other android applications manage the unmanaged exceptions. I do not want to see Application close abruptly as that looks bad.